# Универсальная настройка ajax запросов

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть приличное количество функций с ajax запросами которые содержат в себе повторяющиеся действия, к примеру следующая функция отправляет отзыв о товаре на сервер, перед отправкой вызывается `bodyCover(); $(btn).addClass('disabled'); Progress.start();` и после получения ответа сервера `bodyCover(); $(btn).removeClass('disabled'); Progress.complete();`
bodyCover накладывает невидимой блок поверх сайта чтобы за время запроса пользователь не смог манипулирвать сайтом, второй метод дизейблит кнопку формы, третий создаёт и завршает бегущую линию прогресса в самом верху сайта (как на ютуб). Так вот эти 3 метода расположны во многих функциях и мне хотелось бы узнать как лучше создать универсальную мини систему чтобы это всё выполнялось автоматически во всех аякс запросах без повтора кода.

```
function addReview(form, btn) {
bodyCover(); $(btn).addClass('disabled'); Progress.start();

$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data) {
        bodyCover(); $(btn).removeClass('disabled'); Progress.complete();
    }
})
```

}

Comment: читать тут https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/, отдельно обратить внимание на желтый блок

Comment: Кстати то что у вас там под многоточием скрывается в начале то же может быть важно. Там могут быть какие то стандартные параметры к вашему беку и т.п. И в таких случаях обычно делают функцию обертку, которая принимает все параметры, делает доп действия, делает вызов $.ajax и так же как сейчас на вход принимает callback функцию для результатов и/или возвращает промис

Comment: y ajax есть метод beforeSend.... туда запуск прогресса пихать, а в success и fail - раздизейбливание и убирание прогресса......